# No Route Found Error in custom rails params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, url-routing

I'm working on an application where I've had to put together some custom rails parameters for the routes and I keep getting `no route found` errors when I try to access the page associated with the `show` method. The application is allowing me to reach my `edit` pages, so I know it's working on some level but I have to have an error I'm not seeing somewhere that's messing with the normal view. The custom parameters rely on an `:identifier` that has been custom created for each object. Because the application manages several institutions, all with their objects and files, I've had to right several different sets of routes to handle each different thing. The routes for institutions seem to be working fine, but the second set, for `:intellectual_objects` are the ones that aren't working.

This is my routes file (irrelevant parts excluded):

```
Fluctus::Application.routes.draw do

  get "institutions/:institution_identifier/objects", to: 'intellectual_objects#index', as: :institution_intellectual_objects, :constraints => { :institution_identifier => /[\w+\.]+/ }
  post "institutions/:institution_identifier/objects", to: 'intellectual_objects#create', :constraints => { :institution_identifier => /[\w+\.]+/ }

  #Intellectual Object Routes
  #get "objects/:institution_identifier", to: 'intellectual_objects#index', as: :institution_intellectual_objects, :constraints => { :institution_identifier => /[\w+\.]+/ }
  #post "objects/:institution_identifier", to: 'intellectual_objects#create', :constraints => { :institution_identifier => /[\w+\.]+/ }

  patch "objects/:intellectual_object_identifier", to: 'intellectual_objects#update', :constraints => { :intellectual_object_identifier => /[\w+\/\.]+/ }
  put "objects/:intellectual_object_identifier", to: 'intellectual_objects#update', :constraints => { :intellectual_object_identifier => /[\w+\/\.]+/ }
  delete "objects/:intellectual_object_identifier", to: 'intellectual_objects#destroy', :constraints => { :intellectual_object_identifier => /[\w+\/\.]+/ }
  get "objects/:intellectual_object_identifier/edit", to: 'intellectual_objects#edit', as: :edit_intellectual_object, :constraints => { :intellectual_object_identifier => /[\w+\/\.]+/ }
  get "objects/:intellectual_object_identifier/events", to: 'events#index', as: :intellectual_object_events, :constraints => { :intellectual_object_identifier => /[\w+\/\.]+/ }
  post "objects/:intellectual_object_identifier/events", to: 'events#create', :constraints => { :intellectual_object_identifier => /[\w+\/\.]+/ }
  get "objects/:intellectual_object_identifier", to: 'intellectual_objects#show', as: :intellectual_object, :constraints => { :intellectual_object_identifier => /[\w+\/\.]+/ }

  #post "objects/institution_identifier/:intellectual_object_identifier/data", to: 'generic_files#create', as: intellectual_object_generic_files, :constraints => { [:intellectual_object_identifier, :institution_identifier] => /[\w+\.]/ }
  #patch "objects/institution_identifier/:intellectual_object_identifier/data/:filename", to: 'generic_files#update', :constraints => { [:intellectual_object_identifier, :institution_identifier] => /[\w+\.]/ }

  Blacklight.add_routes(self)

  mount Hydra::RoleManagement::Engine => '/'

  root :to => "catalog#index"
end
```

This is my IntellectualObject Controller:

```
class IntellectualObjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  #load_and_authorize_resource :institution, only: [:index, :create]
  load_and_authorize_resource :through => :institution, only: :create
  #load_and_authorize_resource except: [:index, :create]
  before_filter :set_object, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :set_institution, only: [:index, :create]

  include Aptrust::GatedSearch
  apply_catalog_search_params
  include RecordsControllerBehavior

  self.solr_search_params_logic += [:for_selected_institution]

  def update
    if params[:counter]
      # They are just updating the search counter
      search_session[:counter] = params[:counter]
      redirect_to :action => "show", :status => 303
    else
      # They are updating a record. Use the method defined in RecordsControllerBehavior
      super
    end
  end

  def destroy
    resource.soft_delete
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.html {
        flash[:notice] = "Delete job has been queued for object: #{resource.title}"
        redirect_to root_path
      }
    end
  end

  protected 

  # Override Hydra-editor to redirect to an alternate location after create
  def redirect_after_update
    intellectual_object_path(resource)
  end

  def self.cancan_resource_class
    CanCan::ControllerResource
  end

  private

  def for_selected_institution(solr_parameters, user_parameters)
    #puts "In for_selected_institution------------------------------------------"
    #puts params[:institution_identifier]
    #puts params[:intellectual_object_identifier]
    if(params[:institution_identifier])
      institution = Institution.where(desc_metadata__institution_identifier_tesim: params[:institution_identifier]).first
    else
      io = IntellectualObject.where(desc_metadata__intellectual_object_identifier_tesim: params[:intellectual_object_identifier]).first
      institution = io.institution
    end
    #puts "INSTITUTION: #{institution.id}"
    solr_parameters[:fq] ||= []
    solr_parameters[:fq] << ActiveFedora::SolrService.construct_query_for_rel(is_part_of: "info:fedora/#{institution.id}")
  end

  # Override Blacklight so that it has the "institution_identifier" set even when we're on a show page (e.g. /objects/foo:123)
   def search_action_url options = {}
    institution_intellectual_objects_path(params[:institution_identifier] || @intellectual_object.institution.institution_identifier)
  end

  def set_institution
    if params[:institution_identifier].nil? || Institution.where(desc_metadata__institution_identifier_tesim: params[:institution_identifier]).empty?
      redirect_to root_url
      flash[:alert] = "Sonething wrong with institution_identifier."
    else
      @institution = Institution.where(desc_metadata__institution_identifier_tesim: params[:institution_identifier]).first
      authorize! [:create, :index], @institution if cannot? :read, @institution
    end
  end

  def set_object
    if params[:intellectual_object_identifier].nil? || IntellectualObject.where(desc_metadata__intellectual_object_identifier_tesim: params[:intellectual_object_identifier]).empty?
      redirect_to root_url
      flash[:alert] = "Something wrong with intellectual_object_identifier."
    else
      io_options = IntellectualObject.where(desc_metadata__intellectual_object_identifier_tesim: params[:intellectual_object_identifier])
      io_options.each do |io|
        if params[:intellectual_object_identifier] == io.intellectual_object_identifier
          @intellectual_object = io
          @institution = @intellectual_object.institution
        end
      end
      if @intellectual_object.nil?
        redirect_to root_url
        flash[:alert] = "The object you requested does not exist."
      end
      #authorize! [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy], @institution if cannot? :read, @institution
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to access the `show` route (for example: localhost:3000/objects/test.org/126939282):

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in IntellectualObjects#show
Showing /Users/kec6en/HydraApp/fluctus/app/views/intellectual_objects/_facet_limit.html.erb where line #11 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"index", :intellectual_object_identifier=>"columbia.edu/798d6e812041532c", :controller=>"intellectual_objects", :f=>{"institution_name_ssi"=>["Columbia University"]}}
```

The parameters are showing:

```
{"intellectual_object_identifier"=>"columbia.edu/798d6e812041532c"}
```

And I'm getting this error when I run my spec tests on the `IntellectualObjectController`

```
Failure/Error: get :show, intellectual_object_identifier: obj1
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:intellectual_object_identifier=>"kaulkedurgan.org13/39b1eb47-da8b-4145-b03b-5f1851407012", :controller=>"intellectual_objects", :action=>"show"}
```

I just don't understand because the routes are there, and some of them appear to be working in the application, but every single one is failing in my spec tests. Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: tl;dr - sorry.  Can you make this question more concise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route to `intellectual_objects#index` has the constraint that the `:institution_identifier` should match `/[\w+\.]+/`, but `columbia.edu/798d6e812041532c` does not match that regexp. Even when you add `\/` to your regexp, I am pretty sure that the slash will confuse Rails routing system.

Perhaps you want to change the route to something like this

```
get "institutions/:institution_identifier/:some_id/objects", 
    to: 'intellectual_objects#index', 
    as: :institution_intellectual_objects, 
    constraints: { institution_identifier: /[\w+\.]+/ }
```

And than provide `columbia.edu` (institution_identifier) and `798d6e812041532c` (some_id) as separate values.

Comment: The `institution_identifier` doesn't have those constraints because it's just the `columbia.edu` part. The `intellectual_object_identifier` is the whole one you identified above.

Comment: And your `intellectual_object_identifier` regexp `/[\w+\/\.]+/` does not match: `kaulkedurgan.org13/39b1eb47-da8b-4145-b03b-5f1851407012`. I advise to rethink the idea to have `/` in your variable parts of the url. I am sure Rails cannot handle that.

Comment: I have looked into doing it the way you suggested and didn't have much luck. I'm also very new to regexp. Do you know how I would fix that expression to make it match?

Comment: Just because you asked: `/\w+\.\w+\/[\w\-]+/` would match your example identifier `kaulkedurgan.org13/39b1eb47-da8b-4145-b03b-5f1851407012`. I wonder if Rails' routing is able to handle that, I would be surprised.

Comment: I know it's somewhat messy, but keep in mind that the application has no problem going to `localhost:3000/objects/columbia.edu/12345678/edit`. So I know it can parse the route correctly. It has a problem going to the show page though.

Comment: I should clarify, it can go to that route in the application. The spec tests still say they can't find that route. None of my intellectual object routes are found in those tests.

Comment: Okay. Did not expect Rails to be that clever. Then it must be a problem with your regexp, since your regexp matches `columbia.edu/12345678`, but not the one with the `-` inside.

Comment: Okay, i'll modify it to include dashes and see what shakes out. Did you have any suggestions for the other problem? Why I can edit/update/destroy/etc but not get to the show page?

Answer (score 0):

According to your error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"index"
```

It seems you're trying to access the `index` action?

Being honest, I couldn't bring myself to look through all your routes (you may want to cut out the irrelevant stuff?)

How are you calling the routes with `link_to`?

Comment: I just edited the routes to cut out the irrelevant bits. It seems that way to me too, that it's trying to access the `index` method instead of the `show` method, but I don't understand why or how it's ending up there. And we're using this to link to each object: `link_to_document intellectual_object`, where `intellectual_object` is a variable in a loop that holds the current intellectual object being rendered.